# Connecting PowerPoint and Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

How do I connect PowerPoint and Excel such that each slide in the PowerPoint slideshow shows the next Excel cell in the cell in column A of Excel?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bit of programming, but basically you'll want to:

1. Set a reference to Excel in
   PowerPoint VBE.
2. Figure out where in PowerPoint you
   want the Excel cell text to appear,
   like a Title placeholder.
3. Create a `SlideChange` event in a
   class and with with the slide
   change, read the index of the slide
   and map it to the next cell from an
   array of cells.
4. Place that mapped index text in your
   slide shape when the slide changes.
5. Create a sub that initializes that
   fires the event monitoring - either
   from a Ribbon button, manually from
   F5 or via `Auto_Open`.

If you come back with code that you're having problems with, I'd be happy to consult further.